# How to validate every row of streaming batch?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Need to validate each row of Streaming Dataframe (consumed through readStream(kafka) - Getting error

```
Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()
```

as it is not allowing to validate row by row

I have created spark batch job to consume data from Kafka , validated each row against HBase data, another set of validations based on rowkey and created a dataframe out of it. But here I need to handle the Kafka offset manually in the code.

To avoid the offset handling, am trying to use spark structural Streaming but there am not able to validate row by row.

writestream.foreach (foreachwriter) is good to sink with any external datasource or writing to kafka.

But in my case, I need to validate each row and create a new dataframe based on my validation. foreachwriter - process is not allowing to collect the data using other external classes/list.

Errors:

Getting this error when I tried to access the streaming dataframe to validate

```
Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
```

```
 Task is not serializable
```

when I tried to create a list out of foreach(foreachwriter extended object). Will update with more details (as I am trying other options)

I am trying to achieve spark batch using

```
 writerstream.trigger(Trigger.once)
```

with checkpointlocation

Updating with Spark batch and Structural Streaming Code.

```
      .read
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootStrap)
      .option("subscribePattern", kafkaSubTopic)                
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") 
      //.option("endingOffsets", "latest")
      .load()

   rawData.collect.foreach(row => {
      if (dValidate.dValidate(row)) {
        validatedCandidates += (row.getString(0))
      }       


==================== in the above code I need to handle the offset manually for rerun so decided to use structural streaming.============


   val rawData = spark.readStream
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootStrap)
        .option("subscribe", kafkaSubTopic)
        .option("enable.auto.commit", "true")
        .option("startingOffsets","latest")
        .option("minPartitions", "10")  
        .option("failOnDataLoss", "true")          
        .load()   


   val sInput = new SinkInput(validatedCandidates,dValidate)

  rawData.writeStream
     .foreach(sInput)
     .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
     .option("truncate", "false")
     .trigger(Trigger.Once())
     .start()
```

am getting "Task not serialized" error in here.
with class SinkInput , I am trying to do the same collect operation with external dValidate instance

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood your case, `rawData` is a streaming query (a streaming Dataset) and does not support `collect`. The following part of your code is not correct:

```
rawData.collect
```

That's not supported and hence the exception.

You should be using `foreach` or `foreachBatch` to access rows.

Do this instead:

```
rawData.write.foreach(...)
```